# Prove that $R$ is commutative

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

> Let $R$ be a ring such that
>   $$ x^2-x \in C(R) \quad \forall x \in R,$$
>   where $C(R)$ is the center of $R$. Prove that $R$ is commutative.

I cannot find any route to proceed. How can I start? Please give hints instead of full solution.

Comment: Do your rings have $1$?

Comment: @egreg No, they don't.

Comment: I strongly disagree with the close vote.

Comment: @user26857 Of course I wasn't disagreeing without reason. 1. It was a well articulated question, and specifically asked for hints, not solutions. I saw nothing wrong with the innate merit of the post. 2. Nobody commented saying this post is a duplicate.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As a starting point, consider $(x+y)^2-(x+y)=(x^2-x)+(y^2-y)+xy+yx$.  Since the center of a ring is closed under addition, this implies that $xy+yx\in C(R)$.  Now, there are two cases: either there are no nonzero elements in the center, or there are.

Comment: Thanks. I'll try to solve it.

Comment: For no non-zero elements, the rest is trivial. But, if there are, I don't seem to find anything useful. Where should I look?

Comment: if $c\in C(R)$, then the computation shows that $2xc\in C(R)$.  My thought was that this almost makes C(R) into a two sided ideal.  If, for example, multiplication by $2$ is injective, then $C(R)$ is an ideal, and you can then look at $R/C(R)$.  It is not true that $2r\in C(R)$ implies $r\in  C(r)$ (consider $M_2(\mathbb F_2)$), so care has to be taken here. Since $c\in C(R)$ implies $x(2c)\in C(R)$, we have $(2x)(2c)=2(x(2c))\in 2C(R)$, so $2C(R)$ is a commutative, two sided ideal of $2R$.  Does this help you any?

Comment: Actually, I'm not supposed to use the concept of Ideals here.

Comment: Anyways, I got it. Thanks.

Comment: Might I inquire what ideas or theorems you are are supposed to/allowed to use?  If this is for homework, what topic is it in reference to?

Comment: It's in reference to the chapter named "Rings:Elementary Properties"